# Curried function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

From the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225711/create-new-pandas-column-based-on-start-of-text-string-from-other-column/42225895#comment71621391_42225895)
and since I'm currently learning functional programming I was inspired to write the following (curried) function:

```
def map_starts_with(pat_map):
    def map_string(t):
        pats = [pat for pat in pat_map.keys() if t.startswith(pat)]
        return pat_map.get(pats[0]) if len(pats) > 0 else 0 
    # get only value of "first" pattern if at least one pattern is found
    return map_string
```

Summary of what the code does:

> For a given mapping of patterns to ints, it maps a string to (positive) ints if it starts with one of the patterns and it maps to 0 if no pattern is found (in fact one could and should pass startswith also as a function parameter).

So currently, if you have a `DataFrame`, you would use the `apply` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[ 'xx', 'aaaaaa', 'c']})
      col
0      xx
1  aaaaaa
2       c

mapping = { 'aaa':4 ,'c':3}
df.col.apply(lambda x: map_starts_with(mapping)(x))

0    0
1    4
2    3
```

However, when acting in the Pandas/NumPy world, this approach will typically be too slow. Are there any suggestions on how to speed up this function using NumPy or Pandas vectorization capabilities?

Comment: Not an answer to the performance, but you don't need to wrap the result of `map_starts_with(mapping)` in a lambda, it is already applyable

Answer (score 5):

I'm not completely sure about the specifics of optimizing from the `numpy` or `pandas` side ([here are some things documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)), but, we can optimize the function itself:

- you are calling `.keys()` making an *extra list of keys in memory* (in Python 2; in Python 3 though `keys()` returns a "view")
- you can use an iterative approach switching to `iteritems()` (or `items()` in Python 3) and using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in function allowing you to take an *early exit* once you encounter a key that `t` starts with

Changes applied:

```
def map_starts_with(pat_map):
    def map_string(t):
        return next((value for key, value in pat_map.items() if t.startswith(key)), 0)
    return map_string
```

---

You can also refactor it to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) instead of nested functions:

```
from functools import partial

import pandas as pd


def map_starts_with(pat_map, t):
    return next((value for key, value in pat_map.items() if t.startswith(key)), 0)

mapping = {'aaa': 4 ,'c': 3}

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[ 'xx', 'aaaaaa', 'c']})
print(df.col.apply(partial(map_starts_with, mapping)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your function works with a dictionary `mapping` and any string.  The string could come from a pandas `apply`.   Here I use a list comprehension to apply it to a list of strings:

```
In [2]: mapping = { 'aaa':4 ,'c':3}
In [3]: alist = ['xx','aaaaaa','c']
In [4]: [map_starts_with(mapping)(i) for i in alist]
Out[4]: [0, 4, 3]
```

'Vectorization' is an ambiguous term when dealing with numpy arrays.

There is a `vectorize` function that makes iteration over an array (or list) easy (but not faster):

```
In [5]: f = np.vectorize(map_starts_with(mapping), otypes=[int])
In [6]: f(alist)
Out[6]: array([0, 4, 3])
```

True 'vectorization' requires rewriting the function so that it takes a numpy array, and acts on all of the elements at once (or at least does the iteration in compiled code).   In your case that requires testing all 3 strings at once.  For numbers there are actions like addition and summing that are fast compiled.  But there are few string operations that are truly vectorized. `np.char....` defines a lot of functions that apply various string methods to elements of any array.  They can be handy, but are still basically iterative.

Using `char`, I can test all elements of the list or array for `startswith`, and from the resulting boolean arrays, I can imagine building your [0,4,3] array from  these arrays, but haven't worked out the logic.

```
In [7]: np.char.startswith(alist, 'aaa')
Out[7]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [8]: np.char.startswith(alist, 'c')
Out[8]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

---

Preliminary time testing to see if the `np.char.startswith` is a time saver:

```
In [9]: def foo(pat_map, arr):
   ...:     return [np.char.startswith(arr, pat) for pat in pat_map.keys()]
   ...: 
In [10]: foo(mapping,alist)
Out[10]: 
[array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)]
In [11]: timeit foo(mapping,alist)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.2 µs per loop
In [12]: timeit f(alist)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.9 µs per loop
```

Off hand it doesn't appear to help.

---

Another way to test `startswith` is to truncate the string array entries and do an `==` test:

```
In [13]: arr=np.array(alist)
In [14]: arr
Out[14]: 
array(['xx', 'aaaaaa', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U6')
In [16]: arr.astype('U3')    # clip to 3 char
Out[16]: 
array(['xx', 'aaa', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U3')
In [17]: arr.astype('U3')=='aaa'
Out[17]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [18]: arr.astype('U1')=='c'
Out[18]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Same arrays that I got before

```
In [21]: def bar(pat_map, arr):
    ...:     return [arr.astype('U%s'%len(pat))==pat for pat in pat_map.keys()]
    ...: 
In [22]: bar(mapping, arr)
Out[22]: 
[array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)]
In [23]: timeit bar(mapping, arr)
The slowest run took 4.05 times longer... cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 µs per loop
```

This shows some promise.

---

If the `pat` were all the same length, I could apply this `==` test to all elements at once:

```
In [25]: arr.astype('U1')==np.array(['x','a','c'])[:,None]
Out[25]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

That kind of action is the ideal array `vectorization`.

---

Notice that my attempts to vectorize work in a different direction than your curry.  You create a function that applies the whole mapping to an individual string, and then iterate over the strings.  I instead found functions that applied a single pattern string to all elements of an array or list, and then iterates over the `mapping` dictionary.

---

Here's a function that uses on my array `startswith` expressions, and tries to recreate your `mapping` logic.  It would be nice to evaluate this from a 2d boolean array (size mappings by size arr), but that gets too complicated with your logic.

```
def map_starts_with1(arr, pat_map):
    b = np.zeros_like(arr, int)
    for pat in pat_map:
        c=arr.astype('U%s'%len(pat))==pat
        b = np.where(c, mapping[pat], b)
    return b

In [102]: map_starts_with1(arr, mapping)
Out[102]: array([0, 4, 3])
```

With this small test case, it times the same as `f(arr)` above (the `np.vectorized` version of your `mapping`.  But I suspect that if the array `arr` is much larger than `mapping` dictionary, its performance will improve.  In general if you must iterate, it is best to do so on the smallest dimension.

The last 'pat' that matches will overwrite any others, whereas you claimed to use the first match.  To achieve that I could iterate on `pat_map` in the reverse order.  But since the keys of a dictionary are (technically) unordered, it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: thanks for the exhaustive answer. I expected something like your last function and was looking for an implementation that acts on a array of strings. Of course it's the natural way to iterate over the  keys of the mapping (we expect fewer patterns than strings). Btw. is there a small typo on the 5th line? mapping should be pat_map. Shouldn't it be possible to get same sized patterns by appending wildcard regexes (but probably the equality match will fail there)? Thanks also for emphasiszing, that string operations are generally slower than operations on numbers.

Comment: What do you mean with my logic? I'm open to different approaches, or if you have a suggestion for a better logic, just communicate it.

Comment: I really like the final algorithm, but it could use some better variable naming to be easier to understand. And also some whitespace around the operators :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to writing the quick-n-dirty SO solutions, not the refined CR ones. :)